# Excel SUMIFS with OR, IF, and multiple criteria

Tags: excel, syntax, conditional-statements, sumifs

I am having a problem using SUMIFS. I have columns cost, frequency, interval, and month, where frequency is a string ("monthly", "annually", "other", "once") and the others are all numerical.

I am trying to do a SUMIFS where I sum costs depending on different values of frequency, and have something like this:

=SUMIFS(cost, freq, "="&OR("monthly", IF(mod(month,12)=interval,"annually"), IF(mod(month,interval) = 0, "other"), IF(month=interval, "once"))

In other words, if freq=monthly, sum; if freq=annually, sum if mod is true; if freq=other, sum if mod is true; and if freq=once, sum if month=interval.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be better off creating an extra column with a formula containing all the logic and simply returning 1 or 0, then using that as the basis of the SUM.  Something like:

```
=IF(OR(freq = "monthly" , AND(freq = "annually", mod = true) , AND(freq = "other", mod = true), AND(freq = "once", month = "interval")), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to separate out the logic from the sum. Ultimately, with the month parameter your code couldn't be computed in a single column (for all the mod computations) so I had to create a  table on another sheet for the cost of each line item per month, and computed the conditional monthly costs in those cells, and then did a sumifs for particular cost items. But again, thanks for pointing me in the right direction